# Is the "?" in URLs completely arbitrary (disregarding reserved/non-escaped character problems, etc.)?

Tags: http, url

For example, if for whatever stupid reason I configured my server to parse the URL by splitting the queries by the "^" symbol (escaped if necessary) and the "-" symbol instead of the "?" and "&", would I run into any trouble at all apart from a confused user?

Will the browser/HTTP request sent treat it differently in a way that may be detrimental to my up and coming "power minus" business?

Comment: Your browser might allow a query string whose length exceeds what the browser's limits might be.  Also, you are breaking from a standard, and anyone who consumes your site could have problems (e.g. a third party site which wants to link to your site, possibly with query parameters).

Comment: Ah yes, the browser length is a good point that I didn't think of. But is there any difference in the way the URL is treated in the HTTP protocol, and during the path from client to server? For example, if a URL was "www.whatever.com/^x=2-y=3" v.s "www.whatever.com/?x=2&y=3", would HTTP do different things? For example, would it say, "ok i see those query parameters there, I'm gonna separate those from the URL, etc. and do this request in a slightly different way"?

Comment: Well, speaking as a Java person, the servlet framework is expecting a URL according to the W3C standard.  So departing from this you can expect friction...everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is not arbitrary but defined in the [URI RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) section *3.4 Query*, I dont' think you can change that.

The Query component internal syntax (how name=value couples are encoded) is not defined by the URI RFC, separators can be defined by other specifications:
`&` is defined as separator of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type by [HTML Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#form-content-type). You may change this aspect supporting for example `;` as separator, but you would have in any case to support `&` for when processing the request produced by an HTML FORM.